# Why is 'node' is ' not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file when executed by PHP?

Tags: php, node.js, windows, batch-file, cmd

I made a batch (.bat) file with this code:

```
node -v
PAUSE
```

When I start it via my Windows VPS (Server 2012) it works and shows `v6.11.4` as expected.

But when I do this in PHP:

```
echo exec("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe /c START C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test.bat");
```

It starts a command process on my VPS (I can see it), but it shows:

> 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I translated it from French. Original:

> 'node' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.

I googled it for a pretty long time and tried different things, but I can't fix it. So I ask for help here.

What could be the reason for this different behavior?

Answer (score 1):

node may not be in the PATH variable for the user executing the command. Run echo $PATH

Comment: Hello and thanks for the help, I tried `echo %path%` in a command prompt and this is what I got, node seem to be in the path, and it's working when I don't execute it via PHP as I said in my question. PATH : https://pastebin.com/6tSBq2kT

Comment: does the account running php have access to the `node` command ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Hello, how can I check that ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I only have the account "Administrateur" on my VPS, if that's what you mean.

Comment: did you `echo %path%` in `test.bat` as well ?

Answer (score 0):

try this in command prompt
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Nodejs;%PATH%
i think this will work,
if its not working then paste your nodejs file path insted of c:\programme Files\Nodejs